# Converting Instances of Particles leads to Low Poly Mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, add-on, conversion

I am using Grasswald and have created multiple Particle Systems for an object. I want to animate the object, so I need to convert the particles to a mesh first. The PC already gets a bit laggy with this amount of particles. However, the conversion causes the mesh to become low poly. Screenshot #2 shows the render of the particles before the conversion. Screenshot #3 shows the render after the conversion. The shape of the mesh looks kind of like in the solid view. However, I don't see any options anywhere to adjust the conversion. Thanks for your support!

[image: Particle Systems]

[image: Render of Particle System]

[image: Render of converted Mesh]

Comment: if you press the Make Instances Real in the Particle modifier, the instances should keep their Subdivision Surface modifiers...

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press the *Make Instances Real* button in the *Particle* modifier, the instances should keep their *Subdivision Surface* modifiers.